# Visual basic wrong data received by api

Tags: vba, api

I am trying to sent dynamic data to my api as json object i am received all right data with right format but my problem at two entry first one current time sent all time 00:00 but date sent right and bill number sent to api variable name not value as number and bill amount sent as 0:00 and this is my code.

```
Const SendText ="[{""datetime"": ""{0}"",""isRefund"": false," & _
         """receiptNumber"": ""me!sid"",""amount"": “”me!emt””}]"

Dim SendJson As String
Dim SendDate As Date

SendDate = Date

SendJson = Replace(SendText, "{0}", Format(SendDate, "yyyy-mm-dd hh\:nn\:ss")
xhr.send SendJson
```

Any help please to sent right time and bill number to api

Comment: Unlike PHP, Visual Basic does not scan string literals for substitution values, so it is not going to automatically resolve your `me!sid` and `me!emt`. Substitute them manually like you do with the date. Better yet, [generate proper json](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to perform the replacements: this avoids nested calls to `Replace()` or a long list of individual calls.

For example:

```vb
Const SendText ="[{""datetime"": ""{dt}"",""isRefund"": false," & _
         """receiptNumber"": ""{rn}"",""amount"": ""{amt}""}]"

Dim SendJson As String
Dim SendDate As Date

SendDate = Date

SendJson = ReplaceTokens(SendText, "{dt}", Format(SendDate, "yyyy-mm-dd hh\:nn\:ss", _
                                   "{rn}", me!sid, _
                                   "{amt}", me!emt)

xhr.send SendJson
```

Function:

```vb
'Replace tokens in `msg`: pass pairs of token/replacement values to `args()`
'Eg:  s = ReplaceTokens("Please {verb} this {noun}","{verb}","review","{noun}","report")
Function ReplaceTokens(msg As String, ParamArray args()) As String
    Dim i As Long, rv As String
    rv = msg
    For i = LBound(args) To UBound(args) Step 2
        rv = Replace(rv, args(i), args(i + 1))
    Next i
    ReplaceTokens = rv
End Function
```